# Couldn't find executable named teleop_twist_keyboard.py

Tags: ros, gazebo

I tried to control my bot using teleop_twist_keyboard.But I just cannot run  teleop_twist_keyboard.py.Having examed the package,I thought I install the package correctly.I just cannot find out the reason.I have tried to edit the CMakeLists.txt file ,but the file is read only.Can anyone help me
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Source you environment `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`
2. Try running without .py `rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard`

It should work most probably else try running this:
`rospack list | grep teleop_twist_keyboard`
if you don't see anything its probably not installed properly.

UPDATE:
The issue is with this command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`, it creates a symlink between python and python3. But ROS melodic requires python2 not python 3. so you need to remove the symlink then install python 2 and create a symlink with python 2 and then run it again. I'll write the commands you need to follow.

- `sudo rm /usr/bin/python` to remove the symlink from python to python 3
- `sudo apt install python2.7` check your `/usr/bin/`directory if python2 present skip to next step.
- `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python` creates symlink with python2
- `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` source your ros env.
- `rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py`

EXTRA:

```
user:~$ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
Waiting for subscriber to connect to /cmd_vel
^CGot shutdown request before subscribers connected
user:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python': File exists
user:~$ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
user:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
user:~$ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named teleop_twist_keyboard.py below /opt/ros/melodic/share/teleop_
twist_keyboard
user:~$ rospack list | grep teleop_twist_keyboard
teleop_twist_keyboard /opt/ros/melodic/share/teleop_twist_keyboard
user:~$ sudo rm /usr/bin/python
user:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
user:~$ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
Waiting for subscriber to connect to /cmd_vel
Waiting for subscriber to connect to /cmd_vel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I followed the 2 steps you suggest. Unfortunately，I failed.Then I run the pack list order,it showed that "teleop_twist_keyboard /opt/ros/melodic/share/teleop_twist_keyboard".I cannot make head of it

Comment: I have updated the answer try it. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you for all your assistance!I really learned a lot!